# Disable Alt-hold for CodeLens shortcuts in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, configuration, keyboard-shortcuts

When I press Alt in visual studio while my cursos is placed on a method or class, Visual Studio will display some number keyboard shortcuts for easy access to CodeLens features.

[image: Screenshot of the displayed numbers on a method]

The problem is that these can cause significant lag. Since I use alt for multi-select, this means that whenever I press alt, I get a lag-spike that ranges from barely noticeable to half a second.

So, I'm looking for a way to disable this "feature" that I never actually use.